# AWS Glue ImportError: cannot import name explode_outer

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

When I am trying to run a spark job in AWS Glue, I am getting the below error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name explode_outer
```

If I run the same code in local spark setup, everything is working fine.

This is how I import explode_outer in code.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode_outer
```

Is there any package limitation in AWS Glue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Glue supports Apache Spark 2.2.1 at this moment. Mentioned function is available  from version 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use Apache Spark 2.2.1 in local setup. You may write your own version of explode_outer() method